# Auto-start after power off in nvidia TK1 board

Tags: power-supply, transistors, switches, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I'm trying to make my Nvidia board (TK1) to boot automatically. i.e., when the power goes off and comes back again i want the board to power up automatically. I have tried the Nvidia forum and found a way to do it, but it works only when i manually pull the charger pin from the jack in the board and re-insert it. When the AC power is turned off (without pulling the plug from the board) and turned on again the board doesn't boot up automatically.

I want to know if it is possible to make a automatic switch circuit that would do the job of push button(which will replace the ON switch)

Note: I was also suggested to use a relay to make the button work, coz of it's bulkiness i cannot use it.

Comment: Reed relays can be very small and would do the job for a power button without having to worry about what circuitry is connected to the button. Here's one that's less than an inch long: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/HE721C0500/HE112-ND/133219

Comment: @DoxyLover the rely would wok fine which can be used in the next design, for debugging purpose i would like to construct a circuit and test it. - Thanks

Comment: Probably shorting the POWER switch would work

Comment: @m.Alin it would work if the power switch is a normal switch.but it is a push/release switch which makes a small pulse to make the line go low and then high again. so shorting will not do any good (tried already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the Answer to do this - use a comparator IC (typically a IC that would generate a reset if the input goes below a certain level). Found one in TI(TPS3700) - just the right one.